# Trying to work with ejs to build to do list keep getting TypeError

Tags: express, ejs

What is going wrong here? Screen shot attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlPCn.png)

Comment: Please always include code and errors directly in the question. Not as screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [app.set()](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.set), not [app.use()](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.use).

Replace

```js
app.use("view engine", "ejs");
```

with

```js
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```